# Clarifications about pywavelet return values

Tags: python, signal-processing, wavelet, pywavelets

I'm trying out [PyWavelets](http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/index.html) and following [this](http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/regression/dwt-idwt.html#discrete-wavelet-transform) example.

```
import pywt
x = [3, 7, 1, 1, -2, 5, 4, 6]
cA, cD = pywt.dwt(x, 'db2')
```

Just to confirm, is cA the scaling and cD the time delay? Any way to change shift/scale step (a and b parameters from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet#Discrete_wavelet_transforms_.28discrete_shift_and_scale_parameters.29))?

Answer (score 2):

No, **cA** and **cD** represent the Approximation and Detail coefficients respectively which are obtained after applying the discrete wavelet transform to the signal **x**.

The scaling and time delay which you are referring to are implicitly modelled when implementing the discrete wavelet transform via a digital filter bank.

- By applying repeated decompositions of the approximation signal **cA** one implicitly varies the scale of the wavelet function used **a**
- The *time delay* you refer to can be controlled by the order of the filter